# How to resize the header logo of magento?

Tags: magento-1.7

How to  resize the header logo of magento??
Please reply soon.. I am Working now

```
<img src="<?php echo $this->getLogoSrc()->resize() ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" />
```

Comment: I have an issue with my logo, I followed normal steps:
1. Magento Admin > Content > Configuration > [store] > Header > Logo Image [Upload]
2. Set Logo Image Width and Height, just fill in numbers, no need to use 'px'.
3. Clear Pearl Theme related cache. But unfortunately even if I try to change the px the logo always looks big comparing to the page as you can see here: https://poykee.com/ Any idea how to fix this? Which pixel size to use for the logo? Thanks! Clemence

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/145272)

Answer (score 2):

The best way to resize an image in `magento isVarien_Image`

```
Follow the below code for resize image
$image = new Varien_Image('/full/fs/path/to/image.jpg');

// you cannot use method chaining with Varien_Image
$image->constrainOnly(false);
$image->keepFrame(true);
// avoid black borders by setting background colour
$image->backgroundColor(array(255,255,255));
$image->keepAspectRatio(true);
$image->resize(216, 139);
$image->save('/full/fs/path/to/save/to.jpg');
```

more clearly

```
$_imageUrl = logo die path;
$imageResized = Mage::getBaseDir(‘media’).DS.“resized”.$image;
if (!file_exists($imageResized)&&file_exists($_imageUrl)) :
$imageObj = new Varien_Image($_imageUrl);
$imageObj->constrainOnly(TRUE);
$imageObj->keepAspectRatio(TRUE);
$imageObj->keepFrame(FALSE);
$imageObj->resize(140, 140);
$imageObj->save($imageResized);
endif;
```

Answer (score 1):

Not possible.
Either you add `width` and `height` attributes on the `<img />` tag, or you put as a logo an image with exactly your desired dimensions.  (You can do both).

Comment: is there any magento function to solve it???

Comment: Read my answer carefully. It starts with 'not possible'. Of course I'm being a little drastic. In theory it is possible but not with what Magento offers. You will have to code everything your self and it's not easy.

Answer (score 0):

The Best Way to do it is With CSS, More Easy and More Clean..

If you want a variable image, you can use %..

.logo img{ width: 100%;height: 100%}

Answer (score 0):

1. Find `logo.phtml` and add an id to  tag.
2. Then add a custom css specifying width and height you want.

Answer (score -2):

Resize the logo with an image editor,  use the width, height attributes of the tag, or use css.

Comment: i want to resize it use functions of magento